# ::before content hover doesn't have smooth transition

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have input that I hide and use :before content to replace it with an image. When we click the input the image will change to darker image (I did this way since I'm not sure if we can add opacity on the png image).

It works, however, the images doesn't seem to load smoothly between the click. It has strange flash or the transition is not smooth, after I check the input, the white flash is gone. Is there a way to fix this or work a way around it?

```css
label{
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #bfd5e9;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.block-main-wrap{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    margin: 40px 0;
}

.block-child-wrap{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

.block-label{
    flex-direction: column;
}

.block-input{
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
}

.block-icon-1 + label:before {
    display: flex;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    padding: 6px 2px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.block-icon-1:checked + label:before {
    content: 
}

.block-icon-2 + label:before {
    display: flex;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    content: 
    padding: 6px 2px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.block-icon-2:checked + label:before {
content: 
}

.block-icon-3 + label:before {
    display: flex;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    content: 
    padding: 6px 2px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.block-icon-3:checked + label:before {
content: 
}
```

```html
<div class="block-main-wrap">
            <div class="block-child-wrap">
                <input class="block-input block-icon-1 activatenext" type="radio" id="male" name="GENDER" value="Male">
                <label class="block-label" for="male">test-1</label><br>
            </div>
            <div class="block-child-wrap">
                <input class="block-input block-icon-2 activatenext" type="radio" id="nonbinary" name="GENDER" value="Non-Binary">
                <label class="block-label" for="nonbinary">test-2</label><br>
            </div>
            <div class="block-child-wrap">
                <input class="block-input block-icon-3 activatenext" type="radio" id="female" name="GENDER" value="Female">
                <label class="block-label" for="female">test-3</label><br>
            </div>
</div
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't used `transition-property` to specified which properties are to be transitioned, so none are.

See also [MDN's guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however, I'm not sure I understand, I don't want to have animation or any flash, all I want is to remove the flash, when I check the input, it's smoothly change to darker image